# Pasar una variable de php a una variable de una funcion javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, html5

Digamos que tengo este ejemplo...

código en php:

```
<?php 
$var1='descripcion con " ';
$var2="descripcion con' ";
?>

<!-- htmlentities soluciona el problema con $var1, sin embargo, con $var2 no... -->

<select onchange="funcionjavascript('<?= htmlentities($var1); ?>', '<?= htmlentities($var2); ?>')">.....
```

El error que menciona la consola es:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list .....
```

Comment: La diferencia es que`$var2` tiene comila simple, mientras que `$var1` tiene comilla doble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si realmente la necesitas así, el camino es scapar la cadena, entonces.

```
addslashes($var2);
```

Comment: Gracias! me funciono excelente.